# How to use fopen to open a file that has a name specified by the user?

Tags: c, arrays, fopen

Right now I have this:

```
printf("Please enter your file name with\nthe file type then hit enter followed by ctrl+z\nthen enter 1 final time\n");
char tempChar;
int counter = 0;
char fileName[1000];
int boolean1 = 0;
    while(boolean1 == 0)
    {
        tempChar = getchar();
        if(tempChar == EOF)
            break;
        else
            fileName[counter] = tempChar;
        counter++;
}
```

where `fileName` would be the name of the file. This command works which is awesome and gives me a char array with the name they want. However, I don't know how to pass this to `fopen()`. I've tried `fopen(fileName, "r");` and I've tried it with quotes over filename. I also tried doing `fopen("%c",&fileName,"r");` I believe this is happening because of the extra garbage that comes after in the 1000 length character array but how do I resolve the issue?

Comment: I did the 4 space thing to specify what was code and what wasn't but it wont work sorry if it looks like a hot mess.

Comment: Add a trailing null to the string after you read the last character from the user. Or use a library function to read the input instead of writing your own :)

Comment: You want to read on how C emulates the data type "string" as it does not exist in this language in general and on `0`-terminated `char`-arrays in particular.

Comment: Or perhaps just read a C primer.

Comment: With this code, the <enter> will be stored at the end of the filename. Maybe you want to change EOF to `'\n'` so it stops when the user presses enter.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in C need to be terminated with a null character (`'\0'`), which you failed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you don't *need* to get and `EOF`, explicitly, just check for the newline (`'\n'`), then null terminate the array and pass that to `fopen()`.

Something like

```
while(1)
    {
        tempChar = getchar();
        if(tempChar == '\n'){
            fileName[counter] = '\0';  //null-terminate
            break;
            }
        else
            fileName[counter] = tempChar;
        counter++;
}
```

will do the job.

That said, FWIW,

- `getchar()` returns an `int`, which may not fit in a `char` (example in hand, `EOF`), so change the `tempChar` to `int` type, for better.
- always initialize your local variables, like `char fileName[1000] = {0};`

Another easier approach would be using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read the input from the user at once, process (remove terminating null) and pass that to `fopen()`.

Comment: so I switched the if statement to say if (tempchar == '\n'){artname[counter] = '\0'; break; }and the code still fails to execute. Edit you changed yours before i could comment this was very specific help thank you I really appreciate it!